# Creating a submittable chat entry with wrapping text, and "enter" submit

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to find out how to create a submittable chat entry. What I want is a text box that can wrap. From what I have seen so far, this is done with textarea. However, the text area does not let me submit by just pressing enter. It required a send button. How can I have the best of both worlds? (wrapping input text, but also being able to submit by pressing "enter")

This is the code that was working fine, but would not let me wrap text when I inserted text:

```
<form action="">
       <input id="m" autocomplete="off"><button>Send</button>
</form>
```

This is my new code that will wrap text. It will submit, but only when I press the send button. I want to submit when the "enter" key is pressed:

```
<form action="" style="height: 8%">
     <textarea name="m" style="height:100%; width: 80%"></textarea> 
     <button>Send</button>
</form>
```

I believe that the input id section let me submit when I pressed "enter" only, but textarea will not allow me to.

Comment: How would you then expect the `textarea` to get a new line?

Comment: It gets a new line dynamically whenever it needs a new line. I don't need the function to get a new line by pressing enter. It's a good question, I would just rather use enter to submit.

Comment: @user280339 check my answer please

Comment: Frankly, it makes little sense to me to have a textarea with edit unless you allow new lines during edit.  I would suggest a textbox in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will submit the textarea content after pressing enter (like input). I added ids to both form and textarea:

```js
var textArea = document.getElementById("chatBox"); // set the textarea as variable 
textArea.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {  // listen to keypress on the textarea
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {    // 13 is the "Enter" key on the keyboard
     document.getElementById("chatForm").submit(); // submit the form
  }
});
```

```html
<form id="chatForm" action="" style="height: 8%">
     <textarea name="m" id="chatBox" style="height:100%; width: 80%"></textarea> 
     <button>Send</button>
</form>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I think this answer works, just trying to get it working with the rest of my code right now.

Comment: It answers to your question... Good luck!

Comment: Right, just needed to do some stuff with my code. Got it working, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can catch keyup events on the textearea and then submit the form :

```
<form action="" id="yourForm">
    <textarea name="m" onkeyup="submit"></textarea>
</form>
```

with :

```
function submit() {
    document.getElementById('yourForm').submit();
}
```

Comment: This looks like I viable solution. I need the "onkeyup" to be specifically the "enter" button, though. Is there a way I can specify?